# Axiom of Pairing in T. Jech: "Set Theory"

Tags: set-theory

I just opened up the book "Set Theory" by T. Jech and realised two things:

- The natural numbers are defined in Chapter 2
- The Axiom of Pairing is used in Chapter 1 to define ordered n-tuples inductively

At first sight, this is a paradox for me: Don't you need the Natural Numbers for inductive definitions? But I guess that I miss the right perspective on this.

Comment: Tuples are defined in the meta-theory, not in the theory itself, so you are not using the formal notion of natural number (that, as you point out, is not yet available).

Comment: But any statements about the existence of ordered n-tuples (or sets containing these) for every n would fall into the object language (and hence be problematic). Is this correct?

Comment: Existence of $n$-tuples is just the existence of a set with a given form, and you can show something of that form exists using pairing. I guess the counting is formalized in the logical statement that would check if an object is an $n$-tuple. Note the statement $\phi_n(x)$ that $x$ is an $n$-tuple is different for every $n$, and makes no reference to the natural number "n" constructed in set theory

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the first edition of Kunen's set theory book, where the distinction between theory and metatheory is discussed in detail. (Jech assumes one is already familiar with this distinction.)

Comment: Thanks for advice, i like it so far.

Comment: You don't need the natural numbers for inductive definitions. Given any Dedekind-infinite set $X$, for example, you can inductively define a subset $N\subset X$ that is identical in structure the set of natural numbers.